# Disable redo logs on MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, transaction-log

The title is pretty explicit, I just want to disable completely redo logs on  MariaDB 5.5. This is more of a testing database that might eventually be used for a small web forum, but I don't care about being able to recover from crashes, all I care about is saving disk space.

Is there a way to completely disable redo logs? What if I set the max size to 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The redo logs are required by the InnoDB storage engine. The redo logs provide the 'D' in ACID - durability. You can't set the [`innodb_log_file_size`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_log_file_size) to 0 as the smallest allowed value is 1MB. Also, the smallest value for [`innodb_log_files_in_group`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_log_files_in_group) is 1, so you can't use that either.

You can shut down the MariaDB server and disable InnoDB - use these settings in your .cnf file:

```
[mysqld]
skip_innodb
default_storage_engine=Aria
```

Then delete the InnoDB redo log files (by default: `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1` in your datadir - by default `/var/lib/mysql/`) and start the MariaDB server again.

Answer (score 2):

Use MyISAM instead of InnoDB.  That will take between 1/3 and 1/2 the space.  There will be a few differences; read this backwards:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb

Answer (score 1):

mariadb does not support this, mysql support this from 8
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-redo-log.html#innodb-disable-redo-logging

Answer (score 1):

In MariDB you can't disable it, but can limit it to a constant size.

Use `innodb_undo_log_truncate = ON`.

For more details see this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72122560/2755656